# PHP throws exception "Undefined index" when get form value from $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

Exception message: Notice: Undefined index: qtyID1 in ....

PHP file,

```
$_qtyTmp = $_POST["qtyID1"];
```

Html file,

```
<input type='number' id='qtyID1' name='qtyID1' maxlength='3' value='2' min='0' max='100'>
```

Comment: wheres your `form` ?

Comment: the code posted above is not, in and of itself, sufficient to find the problem. Please show a more complete version of the code rather than just snippets which are themselves fine.

Comment: check your form's method, is it `POST` ?

Comment: Many thanks RamRaider and Sofyan Thayf.

I found that when I remove id='qtyID1', php can get the value now.
Many thanks for your prompt help!!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this occurs when you miss-typed your form method as `get`. 
Check your form's method attribute. It should be as follows,

```
<form method="post" ...>
```

You can learn more on HTML  method Attribute from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)